# SplitViewController shows detail iPad Pro portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

SplitViewController shows only detail controller at first launch in iPad Pro Portrait mode

It should be display both master and detail controller together in portrait mode

Preview:

**Before Dragging (first time launch app)**

[image: Before Dragging]
**After dragging from left side**

[image: After dragging from left side]

Help me as i am using split controller very first time

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @janukansagra you can create new master-detail project and check this in simulator too

Comment: I've checked this issue and go through my answer , You'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this in your `DetailViewController`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }
```

Thanks!